# Align list horizontally with css

Tags: css, list, html

I am trying to align horizontally a list containing radio buttons within a div.
The example can be seen at the following address

http://shopper.webresponsive.co.uk/index.php/blinds/roman-blinds/mairo-mademoiselle-fabric-white-blue.html

I have tried to add to the css the following but no luck:

```
 .options-list ul li {
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: how about styling the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

```css
.options-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

The element with the class of `options-list` is itself a `ul`, so you don't want to include `ul` in your selector.